# Best way to learn recursive statements and understand them?

Tags: java, recursion

I am having such a tough time reading and understanding recursive statements in java.

if my professor shows us code and asks what does this do? what does it return?...I find myself staring at the code as if its going to eventually make sense...but it NEVER does.

examples like---

```
public static Int mystery(int[][] a, int b) {
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
           for (int j = 0; j < a.length; i++){
             x += (a([i][j] == b) ? 1 : 0;
        }

   }
  return x:
}
```

what does mystery (a, 8) return where a = 
{{6, 4, 5, 8},{4, 6, 4, 8,}, {7, 3, 6, 4,}, {1, 5, 7, 8}}

can someone please explain?  thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with recursion. In recursion a function calls itself until an exit condition is given.

Comment: Break the problem into parts. Which parts do you not understand?

Comment: You have the second loop as `for (int j = 0; j < a.length; i++)`.  If that's not a typo, then whatever `mystery` is _supposed_ to do, it's likely doing wrong.  Chances are that loop should read `for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)`...

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! As @Juan notes, 'recursive' isn't the right term for this: maybe you mean ‘loops’, or specifically ‘nested loops’?

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the references to recursion and to fix the bugs identified by Kevin Anderson, and removed a stray `(`, as the core of the question seems to be about understanding loops. Hopefully this isn't too disruptive a change.

Answer (score 1):

Hi welcome to the world of programming
This is not recursive programming. Recursive is when a function calling itself.
For example, delete files() -> which will call itself again when there is folder, and you want to delete files under it again and again.

Your example is called a 'Nested Loops' -> Loops of Loops, and the condition 'a.length' being used in both i and j is wrong.

You are trying to loop arrays of arrays, a 3d table. It should be something like this.

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; ++j){
        if (a[i][j] == b) {
            ++x;
        }
}
return x;
```

Changes:

1. Try not to use 'ternary operator' `?:` as this might confuse you as a beginner.
2. the max length of inner loop should be a[i]'s length
3. using ++i is better than i++ if you are not using the value directly.

Imagine 

`[[1,1,1],
[2,2]]`

in your first loop, a[0].length will be 3.
in your second loop, a[1].length will be 2.

as for ++i vs i++:

```
++i is modifying i directly, making the value +1 instantly
i++ means var b = i; i = b + 1;
```

it is creating a new temporary variable to hold the original `i` value.
example:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
System.out.println(i++); // will print 0, but i will be 1 moving forward
System.out.println(++j); // will print 1, and j will be 1 moving forward
```

you will learn more on this in future.

Comment: A comment on `++i` versus `i++`: there is no difference in the generated bytecode as long as you don't use the value otherwise (i.e. you don't write `int x = i++;`)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you don't understand something, don't just keep staring at it expecting it to suddenly make sense, as that's likely to just be frustrating. Instead, try to break it down into smaller parts, and work from what you know and expand from that, piece by piece.

That's easier said than done, though. How do you split it up? Here are two approaches: you'll need both.

### Low level

One way is to ‘dry run’ the code, instruction by instruction, as if you were the computer. This is slow and tedious, but it gives you the best insight into what the computer is actually doing.

Take a piece of paper, or the virtual equivalent such as a spreadsheet. Make a column for each variable in the method: a, b, x, i, j. (Make the one for a extra wide.)

The method starts with parameters being set, so write the array under a and 8 under b. Next, x is set to 0, so write that under x. Then i is set to 0, and compared to a.length. The array a has four items, the inner arrays, so the length is 4 and the current value of i, 0, is less than that, so the condition is true and we enter the body of the outer loop.

The body of the outer loop contains only the inner loop, which sets j to 0 and compares it to a.length. It's less, so enter the body of the inner loop.

The inner loop body does a few things starting on the right of the =, first working out what a[i] means. Currently i is 0, so that's a[0], which is the first sub array. Then work out a[0][j], which is a[0][0], which is 6. That's not equal to b, so the condition is false: take 0 and add it to the
number under x, 0, and write the result under x to replace the current value. (Replacing 0 with 0? Yes, this doesn't actually change anything.)

Now that you've finished this iteration of the inner loop body, do the i++ (which should probably be j++) by replacing i's 0 with 1. Then do the test again: j is still less than 4, so do the inner loop body again, this time with a[1][0].

I'm going to stop here because it really is tedious, but hopefully you can see the process. The inner loop continues until its condition becomes false, then the outer loop increments i, starting the inner loop again but this time looking at a[1][0], a[1][1], and so on. That continues until the outer loop also makes its condition true. Finally, the last value of x is returned, and if you go through all the steps you'll get the same result the computer would. (Try it: once you get the hang of it, it'll be quicker than reading through the above, thank goodness.)

Okay, so that gives you the same sequence of steps the computer takes, and sometimes that level of detail is invaluable, especially when you have a bug such as assigning to the wrong variable name. But you may still end up not knowing *why* those particular operations, not seeing the wood for the trees. How can you work out what the purpose of the algorithm is?

### High level

Another way we can look at the method is to work out what each statement does, and what the possible cumulative effect could be. For instance, the outer loop steps through each of the nested arrays, and the inner loop steps through each number within a nested array: so in combination, they step through every number within the array a. So something is happening with all the numbers.

Also, x is set to 0 at the start, and within the loops it sometimes has 0 added and sometimes 1. That tells us it's a counter, and by the end it'll tell us how often the condition was true: that is, how many of the numbers within a are equal to b. And so that's what the method returns: how many times b appears in a.

We can also tell the minimum value returned (0, when none of the numbers match), and the maximum (the total count of numbers, because at most 1 is added for each of them).

This is much more useful: we know what the method can be used for, and we can work out what the worst cases are: if we give it more than four billion numbers, a 32-bit int for the result wouldn't be enough, for instance; but it won't run forever (assuming j++) because the array has a fixed size, and it won't run out of memory because it doesn't allocate any other than for the variables.

But you need to be careful with this approach, because it's easy to make assumptions and miss details that change the outcome significantly: use the wrong kind of comparison or the wrong variable, or forget to clear a total, say, and you can end up with code that doesn't do what you think it does.

That can result in some of the most annoying bugs, when you stare at your code and you're *sure* it's right but somehow it still gives you the wrong answer. When that happens to you, switch to dry-running, re-examine your assumptions, or show your code to someone else: without your high-level knowledge of what the code *should* do, they can spot what it *actually* does.

Ultimately this is all a skill that you'll learn with practice, so keep writing and reading code.